# Get values in continuous cells from a column with gaps

Tags: excel

How can I put the values in a column without any gaps from a column with gaps?

Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of input and required output.

```
Index Input Output
  1    10    10
  2          15
  3    15    55
  4          12
  5          27
  6    55
  7    
  8    12
  9    27
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Index is column A, Input column B, and Output Column C. Add this code to a module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveBlanks()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy Range("C2")
    ' Start at the bottom of the range and work your way up
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Len(Range("C" & i)) = 0 Then Range("C" & i).Delete shift:=xlUp
    Next
End Sub
```

You can also use an array formula to achieve the same result.

Give your input range (the one with unwanted blanks) a name. I called mine nrWithBlanks. Paste this formula into all the rows in the output column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(nrWithBlanks,SMALL((IF(LEN(nrWithBlanks),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(nrWithBlanks))))),ROW(A2)),1),"")
```

Since it is an array formula, you'll need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after pasting it into the cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about the order of the data. You could sort the range to exclude blanks from the data